# [: too many arguments when taking * as an input

Tags: linux, bash, loops, while-loop, calc

So I have to make this little calculator in bash with some simple functions which you can see below in the code(which is the debug version). However during execution I'm having an issue where inputting * into operation2 is giving me [: too many arguments, this however does not occur with operation1.

I need the calculator to take this input for inputs like 1+1*2 etc as the script needs to keep going till the user enters "=" hence the while ! loop. I am new to batch scripting so I have no clue what I have to change. I know from debugging it is calling up a list of the files in the dictionary this script is located in, so I believe it must be misinterpreting the command.

The code is as follows with the issue happening when reading in * on either operation2. It works however for all the other inputs (+, -, /, =)

```
#bin/bash +x

begin=$(date +"%s")

echo "Please Enter Your Unix Username:"
read text

userdata=$(grep $text /etc/passwd | cut -d ":" -f1,5,6 | tr -d ',')
echo "The User: $userdata" >> calcusers.txt
date=$(date)
echo "Last Ran calculator.sh on: $date " >> calcusers.txt
echo "---------------------------------------------------------" >> calcusers.txt

name=$(grep $text /etc/passwd | cut -d ":" -f5 | cut -d\  -f1)
echo -n "Hello" $name &&  echo  ", Welcome to calculator.sh."
echo "To begin using calculator.sh to do some calculations simply type a number"
echo "below, followed by the type of sum you want to perform and the input for"
echo "a second number, third and so on. To output the equation simply type =."
set -x
echo "Please Enter a Number:"
read number1
echo "Would you like to Add(+), Subtract(-), Multiply(*) or Divide(/) that number?"
read operation1
echo "Please Enter a Number:"
read number2
total=$(echo "$number1$operation1$number2" | bc)
echo "Would you like to Add(+), Subtract(-), Multiply(*), Divide(/) or Equals(=) that equation?"
read operation2

while [ ! $operation2 = "=" ]
do
     echo "Please Enter a Number:"
     read number3
     total=$(echo "$total$operation2$number3" | bc)
     echo "Would you like to Add(+), Subtract(-), Multiply(*), Divide(/) or Equals(=) that equation?"
     read operation2
done
set +x
echo -n "The total of the equation is" $total && echo "."
termin=$(date +"%s")
difftimelps=$(($termin-$begin))
echo "Thanks for using calculator.sh!"
echo "$(($difftimelps / 60)) minutes and $(($difftimelps % 60)) seconds has passed since the Script was Executed."

exit 0
```

Comment: Have you tried using `'*'` instead of `*` directly?

Comment: `*` unquoted is a shell wildcard.

Comment: That works thank you, but the point behind this is that it's used by any old user so really I need it so that just * can be inputted.

Comment: How comes this issue does not effect the first operation input then?

Comment: + read number3
4
++ echo '2'\''*'\''4'
++ bc
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: '
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: '

Comment: that is what it results in due to reading in the quotations in the sum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quote your variables everywhere:

```
while [ ! "$operation2" = "=" ]
# ........^............^
```

Also, you should expect invalid input from your users

```
while [ ! "$operation2" = "=" ]
do
    case "$operation2" in
        [*/+-])
            echo "Please Enter a Number:"
            read number3
            total=$(echo "$total$operation2$number3" | bc)
            ;;
        *)  echo "Invalid operation: '$operation2'"
            ;;
    esac
    echo "Would you like to Add(+), Subtract(-), Multiply(*), Divide(/) or Equals(=) that equation?"
    read operation2
done
```

Comment: Hi that amazing thank you but after adding in the the invalid code to re-ask users when they make mistakes (which I have been struggling to find out myself, so thanks for that) it's reading * as Invaild.

Comment: Try `'*'|/|+|-) ` instead